# Accept DB Writes faster than the DB can actually write them

Tags: performance, architecture, sybase, database, oracle-coherence

We have a solution which is spread globally across a few Sybase DB servers and fronted by an Oracle Coherence cache.

Now, we need to support 'cache speed writes', yet due to the internationally-replicated nature of our DB, we need to accept data for DB persisting faster than the DB can actually write the data, which you will probably all agree is quite a problem.

I am therefore wondering what the recommended approach to tackle this situation would be.

Points of note:

- There are no constraints
- There are multiple shards split according to usage statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use horizontal partitioning on some of the larger and more frequently accessed tables, which is something that is natively supported by Sybase ASE 15+ and is transparent to client applications.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to consider:

DB may potentially write slower than you need if you're writing to a read-optimized database or tables. There could be a lot of constraints and indexes involved, and a lot of time "wasted" having them checked and re-calculated.

You might want to consider a separate schema or set of tables with an appropriate write-optimized storage engine and no indexes. There could be substantial performance gains here.

There will be another process then that will transfer data from write-optimized to read-optimized (permanent) schema.

In essence, if a synchronous process running into limitations, one would split it in multiple asynchronous processes with introduction of throttling and/or queue mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... the DB is actually more of a 'bucket', as in, there are almost no constraints and indexes on this DB (other than primary key) and it is also already split over multiple databases. One approach we have considered is to write to a temporary queue (as you say) stored on a high speed raid, yet I don't find this elegant and was wondering what the alternatives are.